How exactly are area integrals in the complex plane defined?
I've been thinking about integrals over open sets in the complex plane. This was a topic that was never discussed when I was in university.
If $U$ is some connected open set in the complex plane, and $\phi:U\to \mathbb C$, how exactly do we define
$$\int_U \phi~\mathrm d\mu$$
? Where, $\mu$ is the Euclidean measure in the complex plane (How is this exactly defined as well?)

I suppose the most straightforward way is to find some function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C$ such that , $\forall z\in\mathbb C$,
$$\phi(z)=f(\Re z,\Im z)$$
And then find some set $U'\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ that is isomorphic to $U$, i.e
$$\forall z\in\mathbb C, \\ z\in U\implies (\Re z,\Im z)\in U' \\ z\notin U\implies (\Re z,\Im z)\notin U'$$
And then to define
$$\int_U \phi~\mathrm d\mu \equiv \int_{U'} f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

But to me, this seems rather messy. Is there some way to rigorously define integration over open domains in the complex plane without having to resort to translating the problem back over to $\mathbb R^2$ ?
Thanks.

This is a great question! I believe that a useful notion can be defined using differential forms. Try looking up the area element $dz \wedge d\bar{z} \propto dx \wedge dy$. I also think that Bernstein and Gay Multiple Complex Variables introduces this idea in the first chapter. One final thing, you can still employ the generalized Stoke's theorem with complex differential forms (with $\partial_\bar{z}$), so many of the ways we evaluate area integrals still rely on expressing them as contours and using the Cauchy integral theorem. Hopefully, my comment was helpful. If not, please disregard.

@Talmsmen Thanks for the comment. Would you mind elaborating on the details of using Stokes's theorem? Perhaps in an answer?

Sure, I'll try to get back to you in about an hour. Thanks

$\Bbb C$ is just $\Bbb R^2$ with a multiplication operator. Integration on $\Bbb C$ is defined as integration on $\Bbb R^2$. Even path integration into $\Bbb C$ is path integration into $\Bbb R^2$ using that additional multiplication operation to simplify the integral expression. This is why complex analysis books don't go to any real effort to define integration. It is already defined.
